# Facebook Canvas Setting not any more in the Advanced Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I am trying to find the canvas fluid options for a Facebook page tab. Unfortunately they are not any more in the Advanced section.

Answer (score 1):

The page sizes for a facebook page tab can either be narrow or wide and these options are available for you to select on the basic tab, when you select that your app is a page tab. There is information about this here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ . Please refer to the docs as this isn't really a suitable question for stackoverflow.  Standard applications can use a fluid width as outlined here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/